# Linear independence of matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove the following:

Suppose $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k$ are matrices whose spectra are disjoint. Then if for all $t$, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k q_i e^{t A_i} = 0 $$ then $$q_1 = q_2 = \ldots = q_k = 0$$.

This is not homework, and in fact I'm not completely certain this statement is correct.

Comment: To be clear: the values $q_i$ are scalars, right?

Comment: yes, $q_i$ are scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q_i \ne 0$, the Laplace transform of $q_i e^{tA_i}$ (for $\text{Re}(s)$ sufficiently large) is 
$$q_i \int_0^\infty e^{tA_i - st I}\ dt = q_i (sI - A_i)^{-1}$$
which has poles at the eigenvalues of $A_i$, and since these eigenvalues for
different $i$ are disjoint those will also be poles of the Laplace transform
of $\sum_i q_i e^{tA_i}$.  We conclude that $\sum_i q_i e^{tA_i}$ can't be $0$.

Somewhat more generally, this works as long as one $A_i$ has an eigenvalue that is not an eigenvalue of any other $A_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! A couple of points: first, the Laplace transform exists when $s$ is larger than the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue of any $A_i$. Given that, isn't more work necessary in extending this proof to the case when one $A_i$ has an eigenvalue that the others do not have? After all, maybe we can't let $s$ approach that eigenvalue because of the Laplace transform may not exist in its neighborhood.

Comment: Secondly, I wonder if any alternative proofs are possible - ones that do not rely on the Laplace transform. Just idle curiousity on my part.

Comment: The Laplace transform is defined by the integral in a certain region, and has an analytic continuation to a meromorphic function on the complex plane which has poles ...